# Help with GUI issues

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04, intel-graphics, gui

Hello Ubuntu Community!

I run a VirtualBox VM with Ubuntu 22.04 on a Windows 10 host (with Intel Integrated Graphics).
Yesterday I updated VirtualBox to the latest version (from 6.x to 7.0.6) and I started having GUI rendering issues.

I show two examples below:

1. glxgears shows the usual gears moving, but the top bar looks weird, with no content
   [image]
2. I use CERN ROOT framework for research purposes and all its GUIs are now broken (example below with a TBrowser)
   [image]

I haven't found any other problematic GUIs yet, but the ROOT issue is quite big for me.

I tried creating a new VM, reinstalling ROOT, and everything works fine there, thus I think something must have gone 'bad' in the first VM.

Do you have any suggestions on packages I should try re-installing or reconfiguring? I'd really like not to go through a new complete setup of my work machine...

Answer (score 0):

I found that this was caused by VirtualBox' 3D acceleration option.
Unticking the box solved all the issues.

As of now, I haven't found a way to re-enable it without reproducing these artifacts.